# iOS: Disable UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

Is there way to disable all touches on the UINavigationItems in a UINavigationController?

I´m looking for a method like:

```
[self.navigationcontroller setDisabled:YES / NO];
```

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: THats awesome - considering I have never been able to get that method to so anything worthwhile on any component.

Comment: When you do this do the components still look enabled?  Perhaps it would be better to get the barButtonItems and actually disable them or the user might think the app just locked up.

Comment: Then you should just disable all the buttons, p.e [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];